# Webots ROS2 Tesla Example: Running Lane Following Code

Tags: webots

I would like to know how to run the Webots ROS2 Tesla example that includes lane-following code using ROS 2. Specifically, I want to understand the steps required to set up the ROS 2 environment, create a ROS 2 package for the lane-following code, and successfully run the lane-following script within the ROS 2 environment

Background Research:
I have previously attempted to set up the ROS 2 environment and create a ROS 2 package. However, I am unsure of the specific steps and configurations required to run the Webots ROS2 Tesla example and the lane-following script successfully within ROS 2.

I have also explored the Webots and ROS 2 documentation for relevant information but would appreciate a clear step-by-step guide for running this example.  I'm able to run the robot_lauch.py successfully

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to create a custom package that launches the robot_launch.py from another package.

Start with:

1. Create a custom package in the same workspace with the webot package
2. Create a launch file that imports from webot package, and add launch file with the tesla
3. Add dependencies(webot package) in the package.xml in the custom package

Here are some useful links to use:

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-Your-First-ROS2-Package.html

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Using-ROS2-Launch-For-Large-Projects.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sl0exwcg3o8